# Integration Gmail Api with Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, postman, gmail-api

I'm working on a flutter app that has a module which help user to listen to his gmail and notify him if there is a new mail delivered it's look like this bot on [telegram](https://t.me/GmailBot)

for example i want list his all message so i went to this [api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) and tring it on postmant

my request as thier guide is

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/profile?key=AIzaSyB4Eg2A34XlMp89XEdLA0aJUFAsTPn9B3o' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.a0Ad52N395ZScRVeFUSJvAaD8jIQQE3BpdZf4awh-W_XmNc3Gb92N2CPw5Sc3BYz6QrOfPwuqP1YkzMoBxuuYAzkV7vy4MJ2alLiNI3uOfyET9Yiwga7vpVkc81LY5_4FD-ejw83DyOV9janee8EFnKo6JIafbzS6_MeFVXxfTawaCgYKAa4SARESFQHGX2Mi_H5hxg6MtI_NEFJXp91Ngw0177' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

but i get this reponse

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Invalid Credentials",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "authError",
                "location": "Authorization",
                "locationType": "header"
            }
        ],
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

i tried to do Oauth in flutter using

> oauth2: ^2.0.2
> oauth2_client: ^3.2.2
> flutter_appauth: ^6.0.4
> googleapis_auth: ^1.5.0
> extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth: ^2.0.12

no one worked for me, always there is something is missing like  `customUriScheme / redirectUri /discoveryUrl / etc`

anyone could help me how to deal with gmail api, please?

Answer (score 2):

Result is list of gMail.Message

i'll share more snippet of my code

```
Future<void> init() async {
    final authHeaders = headers;
    final authenticateClient = GoogleAuthClient(authHeaders);
    gmailApi = gMail.GmailApi(authenticateClient);

    try {
      gMail.ListMessagesResponse results = await gmailApi.users.messages
          .list('me', q: 'is:inbox');

      for (gMail.Message message in results.messages ?? []) {
        print("Message ID : ${message.id}");

        gMail.Message messageData =
            await gmailApi.users.messages.get("me", message.id ?? "-");

        setState(() {
          messagesList.add(messageData);
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error initializing Gmail API: $e');
      // Handle error gracefully, maybe show an error message to the user.
    }
  }
```

Comment: Error initializing Gmail API: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 403, message: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of testing it in Postman, I opted to code directly within the app. Utilizing the google_sign_in package, I obtained the current user's access credentials/headers and utilized them to authenticate with Google's API package(googleapis).

Get AuthHeaders Using google_sign_in

```
await _googleSignIn.signIn();
Map<String, String>? headers = await _googleSignIn.currentUser?.authHeaders;
```

```
import 'package:googleapis/gmail/v1.dart' as gMail;

final authHeaders =headers; // usersAuthHeaders
final authenticateClient = GoogleAuthClient(authHeaders);
gmailApi = gMail.GmailApi(authenticateClient);
```

GoogleAuthClient

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class GoogleAuthClient extends http.BaseClient {
  final Map<String, String> _headers;

  final http.Client _client = http.Client();

  GoogleAuthClient(this._headers);

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) {
    return _client.send(request..headers.addAll(_headers));
  }
```

Following this setup, you can proceed to iterate through and retrieve messages:

```
for (gMail.Message message in results.messages ?? []) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: could you share all of the code, please? 
what's the results?

Comment: I tried a code like that anyway this is the output i had 
```/flutter (10504): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null, null)
E/flutter (10504): #0  GoogleSignInApi.signIn (package:google_sign_in_android/src/messages.g.dart:221:7)
E/flutter (10504): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10504): #1 GoogleSignInAndroid._signInUserDataFromChannelData (package:google_sign_in_android/google_sign_in_android.dart:111:3)
E/flutter (10504): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: To utilize the Gmail API and Google Sign-In in your Flutter project, follow these steps:

    Configure Firebase with your project:
        Enable authentication in Firebase.
        Enable the Gmail API from the Google Cloud Console for the same project used in Firebase.
        Ensure to add your app's SHA keys in the Firebase console of your app.

This Should Solve Your Error

Comment: i'm already did this steps, firebase auth is enabled, google cloud console enabled and make credential 
the error is still